# Can I do client side websockets connection to Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I see Twitter has a streaming API. I would like to know if its possible to just write a few lines of client side javascript (without giving away a secret key) that shows in realtime tweets for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

Highly doubt doing this without the secret keys. You could refer the codebase below and see how things work.

> https://github.com/javaguirre/twitter-streaming-api-example

Also why would you want to do things from the client side ?

Comment: For a site I work on I want to show the user a site availability status popup as soon as an admin or automated system sends a tweet about the status of the site. If the site is down then I can't use it as a proxy. The site has a system-wide alerting system but I'm looking into Twitter as a way to give alerts when the site goes down.

Comment: Pretty cool idea @TimClemans, but I really don't think you could do this in client side as it would expose your secret key.